# BCD - Karnaugh Map-Logic Diagram-Logic Array

Tags: power-electronics

hi there my english is bad its not my nature language so i translate some words i hope you catch the meaning,i study informatics and i can confess i have trouble with an exercise on the  lesson electronics.I try solve a lot of exercises but i dont know, i stuck i cant solve ,i hope you guys help me with it,i see a lot of this on my book exercises but i didnt find similar exercises not theory spesific to this.I hope here i am in right place you can help me solve an exercise because this exercise i have trouble.I did a work on it but i failed.I know how to to do Karnaugh and etc but i stuck on this.
**The exercise is:**

> Create detector Binary Decimal Voting (BCD),Multiples with 2,meaning
>   2,4,6,8.It given in binary intregers,with 4 bits,b3,b2,b1,b0.

1.Logic Array 
 2.Karnaugh Map 
 3.Simplified logic function
 4.Logic Diagram

Comment: What did you try so far? Which of the 4 requests (logic array, karnaugh map, ...) you need help with?

Comment: i cant understand it what it means multiples 2 ,what multiples?and all  this numbers 2,4,6,8? and 4 bits i cant understand what this exercise asks me to do.I know how to work on logic arrays etc but this exercises is  different and havent found it nowhere.If you could do me the start of each one   i would be happy.Just not tired you

Comment: I don't know what Binary Decimal Voting means (I know BCD: Binary Coded Decimal). I also don't know what the detector specifications are. Are you sure there is not more information except those two lines of the exercise?

Comment: Binary Coded Decimal means.My translation was wrong.what you mean by detector spesifications?yes only those words was .Nothing says about detector what it is

Comment: create detector BCD thats what it says :/

Comment: With detector it means probably it gives 1 when the BCD value is 2, 4, 6 or 8 (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read what BCD is.

Make a truth table, e.g. 2 in BCD is 0010

Call the digits a, b, c, d... so in this case a = 0, b = 0, c = 1, d = 0
and 8 is 0100: a = 0, b = 1, c = 0, d = 0

Make a table for all possibilities.

From that point it's like handling a Karnaugh diagram like you already know (at least you wrote you are familiar with such diagrams).

Comment: simplified logic function??i understand but not much and you dont cover it all

Comment: You can make the simplified function after you finish the Karnaugh diagram ... just read it, it's like any other Karnaugh diagram theory.